# How to remove last words after specific word (.com) in the first row and split the numbers into next row using shell script/awk/gawk/sed command

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I have below sample csv file.

- Need to remove last words after .com in the first column(Host).
- If there is any number in the first column(host) that number should print in the second column  (port).
- Remove http// and https://
- Full file is almost 12 KB,here i have attached sample.

Sample csv file

```
    Host                                                             Port
https://abcd03.face.op.api.example.com/v1/authent/token?grant_type,443 
https://defghu04.core.op.api.example.com/hello1/v4/tokens,443
https://abcdo3.xyz.def.tata.com/v1/xyz/accesstoken?grant_type,443
https://abcdef.clever.api.sell.com/samsung/v1/managements/autoPayments,443
https://abcdefe.orsd.api.ssample.com/auth/v1/customer-management/interacting,443
http://century.test.ext.sample.com:6102/ABC1/Genereate/CreditSale,80
http://century.test.ext.extra.com:6102/ABC2/proxy/sales,80
http://century.test.ext.sell.com:6550/commerce/1.x/transactionProcessor,80
https://century.test.ext.basic.com:6446/tokenize,443
https://sell.test.ext.state.com:6446/transfer,443
https://century.test.ext.sell.com:6446/delete,443
```

Expected result:

```
abcd03.face.op.api.example.com,443
defghu04.core.op.api.example.com,443
abcdo3.xyz.def.tata.com,443
abcdef.clever.api.sell.com,443
abcdefe.orsd.api.ssample.com,443
century.test.ext.sample.com,6102
century.test.ext.extra.com,6102
century.test.ext.sell.com,6550
century.test.ext.basic.com,6446
sell.test.ext.state.com,6446
century.test.ext.sell.com,6446
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at a solution.

Comment: Is the domain always .com? Can’t it sometimes be .org, .edu, etc? Always think about such things, and how they should be handled.

Comment: @mathguy Yeah, only .com and .org needs to be handled.

Comment: @Beta i have tried this commands for first condition sed 's/com.*/com/'| sed 's/org.*/org/' but it is removing other row, third condtion i am using this command sed -E 's_^https?://__', second condition tired a lot for searching almost spent 1 week of time but no luck

Comment: Appears you've attempted to solve it yourself - good stuff - see if this solution works for you: `(sed 's|http.*://||g' file.csv | grep -v ":" | sed 's|/.*,|,|g') > newfile.csv && (sed 's|http.*://||g' file.csv | grep ":" | sed 's|/.*||g' | sed 's/:/,/g') >> newfile.csv`

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks for your solution, is it possible to combine the commands like this | sed 's|http.*://||g' | grep ":" | sed 's|/.*||g' |sed 's|http.*://||g'| grep -v ":" | sed 's|/.*,|,|g'?

Comment: @KalpanaPinninty, Hi Kalpana, I just now recognized it, please always do add your attempts in your question, there is nothing wrong or right in here we all are here to learn, so please do add whatever you had tried in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, i have added in the comments. Sure will do it going forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that your actual Input_file will be same as shown samples could you please try following then.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
match($0,/\/\/.*\.com:[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
  sub(/:/,",",val)
  print val
  next
}
match($0,/\/\/.*\.com[^/]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
  print val,$NF
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                     ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=OFS=","                               ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
}
match($0,/\/\/.*\.com:[0-9]+/){            ##Matching from // to till .com digits then if match found then do following.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)        ##Creating val which has sub-string of matched value above.
  sub(/:/,",",val)                         ##Substituting colon with comma here in val.
  print val                                ##Printing val here.
  next                                     ##next will skip all further statements.
}
match($0,/\/\/.*\.com[^/]*/){              ##Matching from // to .com here, followed by /
  val=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)        ##Creating val which has sub-string of current line.
  print val,$NF                            ##Printing val and last field here.
}
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I have accepted yours as of now i am using awk and sed commands and got the explination as well :)

Comment: @KalpanaPinninty, your welcome cheers and happy learning on this great forums, keep learning and keep posting good questions and answers.

Comment: Generic question, just now came into my mind if anyone refers to this answer probably it would helpful, sometime host will be ip address eg:10.20.34.45,9034 in this case can we add awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
match($0,/\/\/.*\.com:[0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
  sub(/:/,",",val)
  print val
  next
}
match($0,/\/\/.*\.com[^/]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
  print val,$NF
}
match($0,/././.*\.[0-9]*.){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
  print val,$NF
}' Input_File

Comment: @KalpanaPinninty, now that will be completely different question :) because your samples will change too and future users can be confused since there are other answers too, I would request if you can add a new question for it, please  do add your efforts too in it, cheers and let me know once done we will discuss it there.

Comment: I taught the same, Thank you for your input. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

With `bash` would you please try:

```
while IFS=, read -r url port; do
    if [[ $url =~ https?://([^/:]+)(:([0-9]+))? ]]; then
        [[ -n ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ]] && port="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        # if the port number is included in the url, replace the 2nd field with it
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]},$port"
    fi
done < file.csv
```

Output:

```
abcd03.face.op.api.example.com,443
defghu04.core.op.api.example.com,443
abcdo3.xyz.def.tata.com,443
abcdef.clever.api.sell.com,443
abcdefe.orsd.api.ssample.com,443
century.test.ext.sample.com,6102
century.test.ext.extra.com,6102
century.test.ext.sell.com,6550
century.test.ext.basic.com,6446
sell.test.ext.state.com,6446
century.test.ext.sell.com,6446
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#^https?://##;s#/[^,]*##;s/:([^,]*).*/,\1/' file
```

Remove the front string.

Remove the middle string.

Remove the second column if the port is already present.

See [here](https://asciinema.org/a/R3y05xcvfsCMxWmnG4ZW3BKEH) for demo.

Alternative :

```
sed -E 's#^https?://(([^:]*):([^/]*).*(,).*|([^/]*)/.*(,.*))#\2\4\3\5\6#' file
```